# How to run `httpd` in Docker in detached mode using CMD in Dockerfile?

Tags: reactjs, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile -
The image builds successfully but it doesn't run, it stops. I want to access the website being served from the Apache server from Docker container.

```
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build:staging

# production environment
FROM httpd:latest
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["httpd"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should delete `CMD ["httpd"]`, see [this](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/077141ee37fca63972292c562ec0f632d0f831b1/2.4/Dockerfile#L229):

> CMD ["httpd-foreground"]

There is already a foreground httpd there.

**Finally, Why CMD ["httpd"] won't work?**

The `CMD` defined in `Dockerfile` would be acting as `PID1` of your container. In docker, if `PID1` exits, then, the container will also exit.

- If use `CMD ["httpd-foreground"]`, the apache process will always be in front, so the process will not exit, then the container is alive.
- If use `CMD ["httpd"]`, the `httpd` will directly exit after executing, then `PID1` exits, so the container exits.